# "Cut everyone's rep" power broken on "top users" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, fun, unicoins

The power-up

> **Cut everyone's rep**
>    Divide everybody's reputation (except your own) by ten.

does not work on the top users page (see how e.g. Martijn Pieters still has > 220K rep!)

[image]

I paid **45 Unicoins** for that power! It does work but not everywhere! Please fix this asap!

Comment: I'm sure it will be fix by tomorrow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Un. Acc. Apt. A. Ble.

Fix is being rolled out right now. ***Serious business!***

Answer (score 1):

This is a common bug.
Just write a mail to support *dev-null@unicoin.stackexchange.com* and provide your credit card details and a link to your latest Instagram selfie.
They'll fix it until tomorrow.

Comment: I hope no one take it seriously. even if they do I hope they don't provide there credit card details. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green Sorry to say that, but you have to provide your credit card details since paying with bacon is currently not available...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug - just like you purchased "Cut everyones rep" , other people purchased "Reputation to the max"...

This a constant battle - depending on how much "power" you have, you may either succeed in cutting someones rep everywhere, or only in some places.... until they cut yours!